# get center of width in all browsers with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, center

i have following code to get center of width

```
  function alertSize() {
     var myWidth = 0;
    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ||        document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
//IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
   //IE 4 compatible
   myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  }

return myWidth/2;
}
```

but it did't return correct center of screen.

what i need to get correct center horizontal.

thanks

Comment: you probably mean 'javascript' not 'java' tag

Comment: Do you mean "center of screen" or the "center of the browser window"? Why is jQuery mentioned while your codes has nothing related to it? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function alertSize() {
 return $(window).width()/2
}
```

jQuery has already done all the extra work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful: [A simple jQuery Client Centering Plugin](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/459873.aspx)